# copy using istream_iterator

Tags: c++, istream-iterator

What would be end of source in this case when getting a string input from console?

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<std::string> str;
   copy (istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin), istream_iterator<std::string>(), std::back_inserter(str));   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminal input or EOF .
Ctrl+D in Unix.
Ctrl+Z in Windows.